# Is there a utility I can use to detect the capabilities of my Blu-Ray drive?

Tags: blu-ray, hard-drive

I need to find out the capabilities of a Blu-ray drive I have. Is there a utility that can report this information?

To be more specific I want to know the drive's writing capabilities, i.e. if it can write to blank Blu-ray disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SiSoftware Sandra](http://www.sisoftware.co.uk/) is an excellent well-rounded tool too.

Answer (score 0):

I found I can get these details using the [Nero Info Tool](http://www.nero.com/enu/support-nero8-tools-utilities.html).

Comment: You should accept your own answer to prevent your question from being shown as unanswered.  Cheers.

Comment: I will. but the system doesn't let me accept my own answer unless I wait for like 3 days.    The question is still open for answering if anyone else can give a better answer  so, it's still "unanswered" till I accept one. :)